# Datepicker field 'fixes' date after postback

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-datepicker

My MVC3 website uses jQuery datepicker fields, for example to let the user select his date of birth. The entered value is validated in the controller after posting the form, to make sure the age is over 18. This is working fine, except for the fact the datepicker changes the invalid date after postback to the first available valid date.

Submitting the form today with for example 11-11-2000 returns with a model error 'You need to be at least 18 years old'. The model is bound to the fields again, but instead of the entered date, the datepicker changes this to today, 18 years ago, which is 04-05-1997.

How can I keep the original date the user entered in a not too hacky way?

Comment: you need to set `max-date` to `-18` years in your `datepicker` so that it will not set any future dates!!

Comment: It's still possible to enter an incorrect date using the keyboard, even when it's not selectable in the calendar.

Comment: Well you can make the input `readonly`!!

Comment: Not the direction I was looking in, but sufficient, thanks! If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/CkfDP/1615/)**

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var today=new Date();
    var year=today.getFullYear()-18;
    var month=today.getMonth()+1;
    var day=today.getDate();
    var newDate=new Date(month +'/' +day + '/' +year);
    $('#txtFromDate').datepicker({
         maxDate: newDate
     });

});
```

**HTML**

```
DOB: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" readonly />
```